# is it able to directly use socket() API in server while use thrift lib in client?

Tags: sockets, protocols, thrift, thrift-protocol

Is it able to directly use socket() API in server while use thrift lib in client?
As directly use the API include socket(), write(), etc, there is no Protocol here, directly write a struct.
While in client, it use org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol.readStructBegin, readString, readI64, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The common part of any software/communication contract is that both sides must **adhere** to the protocols(s) as specified. But there is no law that you have to do it in one specific way only.